# Translate curl --data-urlencode to Ansible uri module

Tags: curl, ansible

How would you translate this `curl` request to the ansible uri module?

```
curl -G http://localhost:8086/query?u=admin&p=password \
  --data-urlencode "q=SHOW databases"
```

I don't know how or were to put the `--data-urlencode` part

This is what I have so far (not working):

```
- name: Create influx users with POST
   uri:
     url: "http://localhost:8086/query/?u=admin&p=password"
     method: GET
     body: "q=SHOW databases"
```

And the error I get is:

> "error": "missing required parameter \"q\""

The following however, works:

```
- name: Create influx users with POST
  uri:
    url: "http://localhost:8086/ping"
    method: GET
    status_code: 204
```

**EDIT: final working solution**

This working example will show you the current users of your influxdb

```
- name: Create influx users with POST
   uri:
     url: "http://localhost:8086/query?q={{'SHOW USERS '|urlencode}}"
     method: GET
     user: admin
     password: password
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a [urlencode](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#urlencode) filter in Jinja...but there is another problem. A `GET` request doesn't have a body; when you run:

```
curl -G 'http://localhost:8086/query?u=admin&p=password' --data-urlencode "q=SHOW databases"
```

What actually happens is:

```
GET /query?u=admin&p=password&q=SHOW%20databases
```

So you would need to rewrite your task like this:

```
- name: Create influx users with POST
   uri:
     url: "http://localhost:8086/query/?u=admin&p=password?{{ 'q=SHOW databases'|urlencode }}"
     method: GET
```

Comment: This only changes the body to look like:  "body": "q%3DSHOW%20databases", instead of:  "body": "q=show databases", and I still get the:  "error": "missing required parameter \"q\""

Comment: It turns out that `-G` + `--data-urlencode` ends up just adding your "body" as additional query parameters. See the update in the answer.

Comment: When I use `uri: 'http://localhost:8086/query?q=HELP'`, I get a correct response, but when I use `url: "http://localhost:8086/query?{{ 'q=SHOW databases'|urlencode  }}"` I still get the `'missing parameter \q`
Nginx log:
`"GET /query?q%3DSHOW%20databases`
But a correct one via curl looks like:
`"GET /query?p=%5BREDACTED%5D&q=show+databases&u=admin`

Comment: url: "http://localhost:8086/query?q=SHOW%20DATABASES" - This works, if I hardcode the space as '%20' but that is rather ugly

Comment: Does it work if instead you move `q=` outside of the `{{...}}` block?  `url: "http://localhost:8086/query/?u=admin&p=password?q={{ 'SHOW databases'|urlencode }}"`

Comment: Yes, this also works, If I move the 'q=' outside of the curly braces:
`url: "http://localhost:8086/query?q={{'SHOW DATABASES'|urlencode}}"`

Answer (score 4):

You can set `uri`'s `body_format` to `form-urlencoded`, with method POST.

```
- name: Show Databases
  uri:
    url: "http://localhost:8086/query"
    user: admin
    password: password
    method: POST
    body: 
      q: SHOW DATABASES
    body_format: form-urlencoded
```